# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'webkitGetUserMedia' on 'Navigator': At least one of audio and video must be requested

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, getusermedia

I am trying to do a simple audio video capture of the page in Chrome browser via chrome extension I am building. I am running the following code in a content script.

I don't understand why it is struggling to accept my config, I've included both audio and video yet it still complains that

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'webkitGetUserMedia' on 'Navigator': At least one of audio and video must be requested
    at chooseDesktopMedia
```

here is the code I tried:

```
chooseDesktopMedia();

function chooseDesktopMedia(){
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(
        ["screen"]
    , function onSuccess(stream) {
        showScreenShare(
            {
                audio: true,
                video: {
                    mandatory: {
                        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
                    }   
                }   
            }            
        );
    }, function onError(e) {
        console.error(e);
        alert('Failed to get user media.');
    });
}

function showScreenShare(conf){
    var ve = document.getElementById("screen-share");

   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(conf)
    .then(function(stream){
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        ve.src = url;
    })
    .catch(function(e){
        console.log(e);
        alert(e);
    });

}
```

Comment: Where did you get this code? The parameters are incorrect. Use the example in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#width_and_height).

Comment: Is my answer is what you're looking for?

Comment: @aleng testing it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is something like

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(['screen'])
```

or maybe I'm ignorant about it, but what it meant by

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'webkitGetUserMedia' on 'Navigator': At least one of audio and video must be requested
> at chooseDesktopMedia

because in your getUserMedia, you didn't define the constraints with either audio or video, which should be like this

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
.then(function(mediaStream) {
  //...
  };
})
```

---

### Screen Capture

On the other hand, to run screen capture, you will access Screen Capture API with getDisplayMedia(), **not** getUserMedia()

```
async function startCapture(displayMediaOptions) {
  let captureStream = null;

  try {
    captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
  return captureStream;
}
```

because of permission policy, I can't run example in SO snippets, but what you can do to try this, copy the code below, open your console in developer tools, then run this

*disclamer: run at your own risk

```
let getCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
if (getCanvas == undefined) {
  var videoElem = document.createElement("video");
  videoElem.setAttribute("id", "canvas");
  videoElem.setAttribute("autoplay", true);

  videoElem.style.width = '98%'
  videoElem.style.maxWidth = '860px'
  videoElem.style.position = 'fixed'

  videoElem.style.zIndex = '99999'

  videoElem.style.top = '0'

  videoElem.style.left = '0'
  document.body.insertBefore(videoElem, document.body.firstChild)
}


var displayMediaOptions = {
  video: {
    cursor: "always"
  },
  audio: false
};

async function startCapture() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')

  try {
    canvas.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
    dumpOptionsInfo(canvas);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
}

function dumpOptionsInfo(canvas) {
  const videoTrack = canvas.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0];
  videoTrack.onended = function() {
    canvas.remove()
  };
  console.info("Track settings:");
  console.info(JSON.stringify(videoTrack.getSettings(), null, 2));
  console.info("Track constraints:");
  console.info(JSON.stringify(videoTrack.getConstraints(), null, 2));
}


await startCapture()
```